# Is it possible to solve this system of equations in terms of p?

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Given
$$
\begin{aligned}
b(1-p) +cp &= a \\
ap +c(1-p) &= b \\
a(1-p) + bp &= c \\
a+b+c&=1
\end{aligned}
$$

Is it possible to solve a, b, and c, individually, only in terms of p?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Gaussian Elimination using the first three equations which did not yield what I was looking for. I have tried to play around the equations but cannot seem to solve any of a, b, or c in terms of p. Hence why I was wondering if it was possible in the first place.

Comment: Use the first three to get three separate equations for $p$.  Multiply these to determine $p^3$.

Comment: @Saint: The first three equations are linearly dependent. (Add them together, and you'll get $0=0$.) So, try Gaussian Elimination on, say, the first two equations and the fourth one.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 = a + b + c

1 = [b - bp + cp] + [c - cp + ap] + [a - ap + bp]

Substituting the p terms for a, b, and c, we find the p terms cancel.

p can be any number.  It does not affect the value of a, b, or c.

If p = 0, then a = b = c